# Mongoose MongoError: topology was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am running in a MongoError "Topology was destroyed" from time to time. My Application uses nodejs, mongodb, mongoose (4.1.3), express (4.13.3).

To connect to the server i am using the following params:

```
var con = mongoose.createConnection(baseUri, { 
    server: { 
        poolSize: 1 
    }, socketOptions: { 
        keepAlive: 1, 
        connectTimeoutMS: 10000 
    }});
```

That's what i find in the log files:

```
/data/var/www/rk/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}
    at null.<anonymous> (/data/var/www/rk/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:265:47)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/data/var/www/rk/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:77:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/data/var/www/rk/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:121:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

Could anyone tell me what this Error means and how i can solve it ?

THANKS!!!

BR,
Martin

Comment: You mentioned the error "topology destroyed", yet the error you posted is ECONNRESET.  Either way, this is a network error.  Either an issue with your connection, or the server is dropping your connection.

Comment: You may want to try var options = {
  server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } },
  replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }
};
mongoose.connect(secrets.db, options);